# Why does LR Classic 11.5 Library Module continue to show files on hard drive after they were deleted?

Tags: lightroom

Why are photos that I deleted from my hard drive still showing up in folders in the Library module. I copied them to an external drive to save space on my HD then i deleted them from my hard drive, yet they still show up in LR?

Answer (score 3):

For the next time: You could also do it the other way around to avoid having to re-sync the catalog.

That is : remove the files **from Lightroom** library and choose *Delete from Disk* on the confirmation dialog. This way, the files get deleted from both the catalog **and** your filesystem at the same time.

[image]

The above message could say *"Delete the rejected"* or *"Delete the selected" master photo [...]* depending on your deletion process (if you rejected the photo or just click on "Remove photo" from the Photo or contextual menu).

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-sync the catalog. Go to the Library module/tab and right click on the top folder that contained the moved files. Select 'Synchronize Folder'. It will scan the folder(s) and tell you what's new and what's missing. Make sure that 'Remove missing photos from catalog' is selected and click 'Synchronize'.